# For which algebra $A$: $\mathrm{vect} \cong A-$mod

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory, examples-counterexamples, graded-modules

In general there is an equivalence between a module category (see 
[Module Category nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+category)) over a monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ and $A-$mod, where $A$ is an algebra over $\mathcal{C}$:
$$\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{C}} \cong A-mod$$
This is proven in [Ostrik, Theorem 1 on page 10](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139).

I now want to consider an explicit example. 
Let $k$ be a field. Let $\mathcal{C}=G-\mathrm{vect}$ be the category of $G$-graded vector spaces over $k$. And let $\mathcal{M}_{G-\mathrm{vect}}$ be the category $\mathrm{vect}_{k}$, all vector spaces over a field $k$. The module structure is given by the tensor product of vector spaces, where we use the forgetful functor on the $G$-graded vector spaces.

Now I want to find such an algebra $A$ as in the statement above. In the proof of Theorem 1 in Ostrik, $A$ is given as $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(V, V)$ for an arbitrary vector space $V$.

$\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(V, V)$ is the representing object for the functor $X \mapsto \mathrm{Hom}(X \otimes V, V)$, with $X \in \mathcal{C}$=$G-\mathrm{vect}$.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to find such a representing object, especially since $V$ is arbitrary. Does anyone have an idea on how I could proceed to get such a $V$ and $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(V, V)$?

Comment: I think that $A$ is the group algebra graded by the natural $G$-action. I will write a full answer later today when I have the time.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, I will look into it but are looking forward to your answer! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a module category over $\mathcal{C}$ given by the forgetful functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{M}=\textrm{Vect}$. Choose an arbitrary irreducible object $M\in\mathcal{M}$.

Now we compute the inner hom $\underline{Hom}(M,M)$. For every $V\in \mathcal{C}$ we should have 
$$Hom_\mathcal{C}(V,\underline{Hom}(M,M))\simeq Hom_\mathcal{M}(V\otimes M,M).$$
For every $g\in G$ let $V_g\in \mathcal{C}$ be a $1$-dim vector space graded by $g$. The we have $$Hom_\mathcal{C}(V_g,\underline{Hom}(M,M))\simeq Hom_\mathcal{M}(F(V_g)\otimes M,M)\simeq Hom_\mathcal{M}(M,M)=k,$$ hence $\underline{Hom}(M,M)$ has each $V_g$ exactly one time. Therefore $\underline{Hom}(M,M)\simeq \bigoplus\limits_{g\in G}{V_g}$.

It is not hard to "guess" that the algebra structure given by composition is the group algebra structure on $kG$. Therefore $\underline{Hom}(M,M)$ is canonically isomorphic to $kG$.

Also one can manually check that for every $kG$-module in $\mathcal{C}$ is free, hence the category of $kG$-modules in $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to $\textrm{Vect}$.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! Could you maybe explain why $F(V_g) \otimes M \cong M$? I Suppose the question actually is, why $F(V_g) = k$... and then I don't quite get the conclusion: If I check that every $kG$- module in $\mathcal{C}$ is free (do have a hint on how to check this?), why do we get the equivalence to $\mathrm{vect}$? I am very sorry for my deficiency :( Thanks again!

Comment: $F$ is the forgetful functor, $V_g$ is $1$-dimensional vector space graded by $g$, if we forget the grading then $F(V_g)$ is just $1$-dimensional vector space, hence $F(V_g)\simeq k$.

Comment: The functor $\textrm{Vect}\to kG-\textrm{mod}_\mathcal{C}$ which sends  $V\to kG\otimes V$ is an equivalence.  Under that equivalence $F(V_g)\simeq (kG)\otimes V_g$.

Comment: I guess the basic (and rather trivial) fact one needs to check is $V_g\otimes kG\simeq kG$.

Comment: Thanks again! In your second comment you say $F(V_g) \cong (kG) \otimes V_g$ - do you still mean $F$ as the forgetful functor or did you call the functor $Vect \rightarrow kG-mod$ also $F$?

Comment: (I'm pretty sure it is the second one, but I just wanted to be sure)

Comment: Yet, it is the second one but under the identification $\textrm{Vect}\to kG-\textrm{mod}_\mathcal{C}$ they are the same.

Comment: I am still not quite done with this statement. Now I found a source which says that the graded $k$-vector spaces are isomorphic to the $K[G]$-comodules - not modules! Is what you said still correct? Tbh I didn't understand your way of proving that it is...

Comment: The source I was referring to, is the script of the following lecture class: https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/schweigert/ws14/hopf.html, where this is said in Example 2.2.8 on p. 23

Comment: Yes you are right - the part "It is not hard to "guess" that the algebra structure given by composition is the group algebra structure on $kG$. Therefore $Hom(M,M)$ is canonically isomorphic to $kG$." is wrong. This is a dual to $kG$ (it has to be abelian, since every module is $1$-dimensional. I am sorry for a bad answer. I will edit the answer so it is right