# Isomorphism between Hom-space and $k$

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, hom-functor

Let $\mathrm{vect}$ be the category of vector spaces over $k$ and let $V \in \mathrm{vect}$.
Can one say $\mathrm{Hom}(V, V)$ (the hom-space in the category $\mathrm{vect}$) is isomorphic to $k$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Certainly not for all $V$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $V$ is finite dimensional so $V\cong \oplus_{i=1}^n k_i$ where $k_i=k$. Then

$$\mathrm{Hom}(V,V)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(\oplus_{i=1}^n k_i, \oplus_{j=1}^n k_j)=\oplus_{j=1}^n \mathrm{Hom}(\oplus_{i=1}^n k_i,k_j)=$$
$$\oplus_{i=1}^n \oplus_{j=1}^n \mathrm{Hom}(k_i,k_j)
\cong \oplus_{i=1}^n \oplus_{j=1}^n\mathrm{Hom}(k,k)\cong \oplus_{i=1}^n \oplus_{j=1}^n k,$$

which is not $k$ in general, but finitely many copies of it. In the infinite dimensional case this is even further from being true. Your claim is of course true when $\dim(V)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! In the answer to my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118727/for-which-algebra-a-mathrmvect-cong-a-mod/3119399?noredirect=1#comment6431673_3119399, the person answering uses $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{M}}(M, M) = k$ where $\mathcal{M}= vect$ the module category of vector spaces. Do you have an idea why it holds there? I remember my professor saying something similar, so I suppose that the claim itself is correct.

Comment: I have in my case a module category $\mathcal{M}$ over a category $\mathcal{C}$ and $M$ is irreducible. Does irreducible mean that $M$ has dimension 1?

Comment: In the linked post you are overlooking the adjective “irreducible.”  Vector spaces of dimension greater than 1 are not irreducible.

Comment: @Randall thanks!

Comment: I want to add a [reference](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simple+object) to @Randall comment